# retrieving from database into table in php

Tags: php, database

im trying to retrieve  data from database and display it into a table in php

i tried this

```
 <?php



 // array for JSON response
 $response = array();


 // include db connect class
 require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

 // connecting to db
 $db = new DB_CONNECT();
 mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
 // get all products from products table
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM glossary") or die(mysql_error());

 // check for empty result
 if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
// looping through all results
// products node
$response["glossaries"] = array();
     echo "<table>";
 echo "<tr>";
 echo "<th>Symbol</th>";
 echo "<th>Name</th>";
 echo "<th>Description</th>";
 echo "<th>Chapter</th>";
 echo "</tr>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

  echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>". $row['Symbol'] ."</td>";   
echo "<td>". $row['Name'] ."</td>"; 
echo "<td>". $row['Description'] ."</td>";
echo "<td>". $row['ID_Chapter'] ."</td>";
 echo "</tr>";


}
     echo "</table>";
header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
// success
$response["success"] = 1;

// echoing JSON response
 } else {
// no products found
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "No products found";

 }
 ?>
```

but i will get a really strange result in the browser it will print the table tags td,tr... and the value between them like this:

```
 <table><tr><th>Symbol</th><th>Name</th><th>Description</th><th>Chapter</th></tr><tr><td>θ </td><td></td><td></td><td>8</td></tr><tr><td>A ⊂ B</td><td>Proper subset / strict subset</td><td>Subset has fewer elements than the set</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>A'</td><td>Complement </td><td>Event A does not occur</td><td>1</td></tr></table>
```

why ?

Comment: Is the file's extension `.php`? Is PHP running? If it's showing the tags as output, then that's a possibility. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: How is that result strange?  Don't you *want* the values to be in the table?

Comment: @David I think he means that the HTML isn't being rendered, but instead being outputted to the browser as text. I could be wrong though

Comment: I think 50% of the questions on this site are _this_.  Just google "php mysql html table" and I bet the first 60 results are from stackoverflow.  cv-pls

Comment: Well, you are setting the content-type to json but expecting it to render HTML? I am confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
```

That's... not JSON data.  That's HTML.  For example:

```
echo "<table>";
```

The default `Content-type` is probably HTML, so you can just remove the `header` line entirely.  If you want to be explicit, you can be:

```
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

Basically what's happening is that you're explicitly telling the browser *not* to render the HTML, but to just treat it like JSON data.  Which is why it's not rendering the HTML.

Comment: That makes sense. However, when I tested OP's code with both headers, received `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent...`. Only by placing the header at the very top did the output come out as OP stated. It should be as you say, yet the header would need to be placed at the top before any output. OP probably doesn't have [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) set.

Comment: i forget to change the json cuz i used the same data with json in android .. worked! THANK YOU SO MUCH!:)

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Makes sense.  I guess I figured that he was buffering somewhere else if the original code wasn't throwing an error.

Comment: @David That could very well be the case then. If OP didn't mention anything about a headers warning, then what you said would explain it.